# Не удаляется программа из нового окна "Приложения и возможности" windows 10

Tags: windows-10, wix

Есть программа, инсталлятор, написан на wix 3.7. При удалении исталлятору нужно запустить вложенный бинарник:

```
 <CustomAction Id="Disable" BinaryKey="SetupHelper"
                     ExeCommand=""
                     Impersonate="yes" Execute="immediate" Return="check"/>
```

При удалении программы с помощью инсталлятора или через окно "Программы и компоненты" бинарник вызывается корректно и приложение удаляется. Если удалять через новое окно "Приложения и возможности", то возникает ошибка:
Product: small_test -- Error 1721. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action: Disable, location: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIA4D9.tmp, command:
Пробовал изменять инсталлятор, устанавливать другие флаги, заходить под учеткой "Администратор" и другие действия. Ошибка всегда возникает. Есть у кого-нибудь идеи как ее решить?